# Runtime Crash when using Navigation on HERE Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk

I encountered some errors at runtime when using navigation. Also, the reference I use when implementing the codes in my application is

[heremaps/here-sdk-examples/navigation_app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app)

[image]

[image]

I get this crash almost every time I try. What do you suggest about this subject?
Here version: 4.8.0.0
Flutter version: 2.5.2 • channel stable

Comment: You are getting "received memory pressure event" logs which means that you run out of memory. Try to run on a device with sufficient memory and / or try to profile your app: Probably you have a memory leak somewhere. In case of doubt, run the unmodified example app and compare the results.